# How can I verify a Google+ local page for an organization with only a PO Box?

Tags: google

I'm setting up a Google+ Local Page for a local organization, which has a P.O. Box, but does not receive mail at all at their physical address.  I see no place in Google+ to add the P.O. Box address, and I don't believe Google will allow a P.O. Box address as a primary address.  Is there any way to get this site verified?

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure if this belonged on this site, but Pro Webmasters seems most likely to be able to answer it...

Answer (score 1):

Google no longer allows P.O. Box addresses in either the address1 or address2 fields of a local page listing.    They did post [instructions for businesses that can only receive mail at a P.O. Box to get verified](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/business/need-advice/VNH9Aa21ShI).  Basically it says you have to contact them, wait for two weeks for them to get back to you via email.  They will then send the verification postcard to your P.O. Box but not put that address in your listing.

Answer (score -1):

Google requires a mail address because he sends there a postcard with a PIN on it. By entering the PIN you verify that the mail address you entered in Google Local Places does exists.

I'm not ceratin, but I think you can entere a P.O. box address, why not? What it's not celar is when you say that your P.O. box does not receive mail, so whay do you have a P.O. box, isn't its main usage to receive mails?!